# Bootstrap 5.3 Tabs controlled via <select>

Tags: javascript, tabs, bootstrap-5

What I want to achive is to change the Tabcontent to the coorresponding  of .

What I get ist a console error:

> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

I tried it with passing only the ID of the tab-pane (val), as well as passing the default nav-tab and try to show the corresponding tab with #navtab.tab('show');

Both options with the same outcome. (Illegal invocation).

What am I missing? Thanks a lot.

```js
const tabSelect = document.querySelector(".js-tabselect");

tabSelect.addEventListener('change', function handleChange(event) {
    
     // get selected VALUE
    let val = (event.target.value);
    
    let someTabTriggerEl = document.querySelector(val);
    
    let bsTab = new bootstrap.Tab('#myTabContent'); 
    bsTab.show(someTabTriggerEl);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<select name="tabselect" class="js-tabselect" role="tablist" data-toggle="tab">
 <option value="#tab-one">1</option>
 <option value="#tab-two">1g</option>
 <option value="#tab-three">TV-3</option>
 <option value="#tab-four">4</option>
 <option value="#tab-five">5</option>
 <option value="#tab-six">6</option>
 <option value="#tab-seven">7</option>
 <option value="#tab-eight">8</option>
 <option value="#tab-nine">8</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Can you include a more complete example with the tab content?

Comment: Why is everyone using the alpha version of Bootstrap lately? Is there some new feature in it you just must have? Otherwise it's not wise.

Comment: Please update the snippet demo above to show the problem. Also, see [ask] and take the [tour] for tips on using this site.